# Journey builder custom split not working for more than 50 records in entry table, is there any limitation?

Tags: marketing-cloud, custom-activity

I am developing marketing cloud custom split by node.js , it works fine for 25 records in journey entry but does not work for more than 25 records , none of the records push thru the custom split step. is there any such limitation ?

Comment: There shouldn't be such a limitation. Each time a Contact arrives at your Custom  Split Activity,  Journey Builder will make a request to your execute endpoint. Perhaps this is on your server end? Where are you hosting this? Heroku? Can you tail the web server log to see what happens when >25 Contacts arrive at your Activity?

Answer (score 0):

We have done testing of pushing 100k Records in one go through custom activities and not had issues. I cannot speak specifically for Decision Splits but system works the same way so I would not see any issues with this

Regards
Doug